# Loosing grafana dashboard on container or, docker restart [Windows+docker+grafana]

Tags: windows, docker, grafana

I have been working on sample project with Windows+Docker+Prometheus+Grafana
Issue:
Loosing all details on grafana dashboard on docker or, container restart. 
All works fine with docker-compose for the first time. 
I have the created the volumes. The application, prometheus &, grafana containers are running under same network, the issue occurs on docker restart or, container restart &, grafana also asks me to change the password, I hope this has something related to volume.

docker-compose entry for grafana:

```
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    container_name: gradle_docker-grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana
    networks:
      - gradle_docker_net
    depends_on:
      - prometheus

volumes:
  prometheus-storage: {}
  grafana-storage: {}
  mongo-storage: {}
  sonarqube_conf: {}
  sonarqube_data: {}
```

Any suggestions would be helpful as I am unable to find anything related to the same.

Answer (score 1):

Did you define the `grafana-storage` volume in your top-level `volumes` section? If not then I'd try that and see whether it solves the problem.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have already provided this in the configuration file.

Comment: @MayankGupta do you mean you have it defined outside of the config section you pasted above?

Comment: I have updated my question with the docker-compose entries for volumes.

Comment: The examples in the docs don't use the `{}` syntax, not sure if that might be related.  The first thing I'd do would be to try `docker volume ls` to see what volumes have actually been created, and whether they stick around after you shut down the containers.

Comment: Thanks but I have checked the volumes as well tried removing '{}', the issue happens for both mongo and grafana, I am loosing data with mongo and grafana both.